# Problematic variables and number of factors in PCA

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I have a problem with two variables in PCA. I obtain  a certain number of factors (lets say n factors), but on the last factor I obtain only one variable (I will call it X) that loads high on that factor and another variable (Y) that has a loading <0,50. If I delete variable Y (because it does not have a loading greater than 0,50), then I can obtain n-1 factors, but also n factors. 
If I look at the solution with n-1 factors, variable X that should be deleted. If I delete this variable (in the n-1 factors solution), and then set n factors again, the solution looks better than initial. But I am not sure if it is okay to delete the variable X because it does not fit the n-1 solution. If I set n factors again the solution would be better (than the case when including the X variable). 
If I would want to keep the solution with n factors, wich looks better after deleting that variable, it this okay? Or should n-1 factors be kept in the solution after deleting that variable?

Comment: What are you doing all that for?

Comment: To retain factors for a theoretical construct, if I understand your questions correctly.